# How to disable the output log in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Very basic question.

Every time in in VS Code and press the letter "O", it opens the output log from the bottom of the screen and it takes up most of the screen space. Not only that, it's also useless for me (at least now) and I don't need it every time I press "O".

Searched in google for an answer, and found nothing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the keybindings in VS Code, [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) may be helpful.